# How do I create a new dataframe from every nth row of an existing dataframe while performing math functions on some columns of the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with daily data of several parameters:

```
     date     pH       alkalinity
0    1/1/11   8.1      87
1    1/2/11   8.3      73
2    1/3/11   8.2      65
3    1/4/11   8.5      58
4    1/5/11   8.0      81
5    1/6/11   8.5      78
6    1/7/11   8.2      67
.    
.
.
.
20   1/21/11  8.4      59
21   1/22/11  8.2      67
```

I want to take the data and create a new dataframe that "buckets" the data by taking the 3rd day (starting with the first), and then create columns of the average of each parameter and median of each parameter:

```
    groupdate    pHavg   pHmed   alkavg   alkmed
0   1/1/11       8.2     8.2     75       73
1   1/4/11       8.3     8.5     72.3     78
.
.
.
```

Ideally, if a day is missing or has 2 sets of data, those dates will be included in the average/median calc (so I'm not just taking every 3 rows necessarily).

I was able to pick out every 3rd line of data like this:

```
date = pd.DataFrame(data['date'])
weeks = date.iloc[::3,:].min()
```

But it just returns ever column of every third line of the original dataframe:

```
     date     pH       alkalinity
0    1/1/11   8.1      87
3    1/4/11   8.5      58
6    1/7/11   8.2      67
.
.
```

I cannot figure out how to specify A) take every third data or B) how to calculate a mathematical function on each group of 3 parameters.

Comment: Sounds like `df.groupby()` or `df.rolling()`, THEN slice it for only the days you want?

Comment: It might be easier if you make sure you have continuous data in your date column.  I would insert missing dates with null values for the other columns

Comment: please tell me if my solution works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample DataFrame**

```
        date   pH  alkalinity
0 2011-01-01  8.1          87
1 2011-01-02  8.3          73
2 2011-01-03  8.2          65
3 2011-01-04  8.5          58
4 2011-01-05  8.0          81
5 2011-01-06  8.5          78
6 2011-01-07  8.2          67
```

First convert to **datetime**

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then use:

```
new_df = df.resample(on='date',rule='3D').agg(['mean','median'])
new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
print(new_df)
             pH_mean  pH_median  alkalinity_mean  alkalinity_median
date                                                               
2011-01-01  8.200000        8.2        75.000000                 73
2011-01-04  8.333333        8.5        72.333333                 78
2011-01-07  8.200000        8.2        67.000000                 67
```

or

```
new_df =( df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3D',key = 'date'))
            .agg(pHavg = ('pH','mean'),pHmed=('pH','median'),
                 alkavg=('alkalinity','mean'),alkmed=('alkalinity','median')) )
print(new_df)
               pHavg  pHmed     alkavg  alkmed
date                                          
2011-01-01  8.200000    8.2  75.000000      73
2011-01-04  8.333333    8.5  72.333333      78
2011-01-07  8.200000    8.2  67.000000      67
```